# jQuery accordion issues - Hover icon and IE7/8 problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to use Jquery accordion in my website and I have a couple of issues that I am trying to address.

Firstly, I can't seem to make the cursor a hand when the user hovers over with the mouse.

Secondly the accordion does not work in IE8 or IE7, but works fine in IE9 and above and in other browsers.

I am by no means an expert in building the code and I have put together something that is almost there - I just need to get these two issues sorted and then I am done.

The link to my test page is:

http://www.micklehamweather.com/test.php

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- DC RSS Feeds CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tsc_rssfeed.css" />

<!-- jQuery Library (skip this step if already called on page ) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- (do not     call twice) -->

<!-- DC RSS Feeds JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tsc_rssfeed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tsc_vticker.js"></script>





<script>
$(function($) {
  var allAccordions = $('.accordion div.data');
  var allAccordionItems = $('.accordion .accordion-item');
  $('.accordion > .accordion-item').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('open'))
    {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      $(this).next().slideUp("slow");
    }
    else
    {
    allAccordions.slideUp("slow");
    allAccordionItems.removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
    return false;
    }
  });
})
;
</script>

<!-- Start BOM Alert Refresh -->

    <!-- JQuery script -->

<script  type="text/javascript"> 
var updatebomalertvic = setInterval(function() {
$('#bomalertvic').fadeOut('fast').load('rss-directbomvic.php').fadeIn('fast');}, 63000);
</script>

<script  type="text/javascript"> 
var updatebomalertvic = setInterval(function() {
$('#firealertvic').fadeOut('fast').load('fireincidents.php').fadeIn('fast');}, 63000);
</script>

<div align="center">
<div class="accordion">
<div class="accordion-item"><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr><td style="text-align:center" class="table-top" colspan="4"<span style="font-size: 100%; text-align:center;">   Alerts  <img width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="Warnings issued by the Bureau of Meteorology" src="images/alert-icon-120.png" border="0">  Warnings  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Fire  <img width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="Incidents issued by the CFA" src="images/Emergency_Warning.png" border="0"> Incidents
</span></td>

</tr></table><div class="type">
 </div> </div>



<tr class="column-dark">
    <td colspan="8" align="center">
<div class="data" style="display: none;"> 
<!-- Start BOM Alert TAS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
               function SetHTML1(type) {
                              document.getElementById("a0").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("a1").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("c1").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("e1").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none"
                              document.getElementById("g1").style.display = "none"
                              // Using style.display="block" instead of style.display="" leaves a carriage return
                              document.getElementById(type).style.display = ""
               }

</script>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<table style="background-color:#9F9F9F; border: thin solid; border-color:  #4A4A4A;  " width="100%">
  <tr>

<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/vic-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show Victoria - Warnings" alt="VIC"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/vic/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show Victoria - Warnings">VIC</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/tas-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show Tasmania - Warnings" alt="TAS"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/tas/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show Tasmania - Warnings">TAS</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/wa-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show Western Australia - Warnings" alt="WA"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/wa/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show Western Australia - Warnings">WA</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/nt-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show Northern Territory - Warnings" alt="NT"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/nt/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show Northern Territory - Warnings">NT</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/sa-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show South Australia - Warnings" alt="SA"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/sa/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show South Australia - Warnings">SA</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/act-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show Australian Capital Territory - Warnings" alt="ACT"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/act/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show Australian Capital Territory - Warnings">ACT</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/nsw-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show New South Wales - Warnings" alt="NSW"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/nsw/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show New South Wales - Warnings">NSW</a></td>
<td width="91.428571428571428571428571428571" align="center"><img src="images/qld-thumb.png" width="30" height="30" title="Show Queensland - Warnings" alt="QLD"/><a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/qld/warnings/index.shtml" target="_blank" title="Show Queensland - Warnings">QLD</a></td>

  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr class="column-light">
<!-- Start Hide All -->
    <td colspan="8"><span id="a0" style=""></span>
<!-- End Hide All -->

<!-- Start BOM Alert VIC -->
<span id="e1" style="display:value">
<table style="background-color:#FFE991; border: thin solid; border-color: #4A4A4A;  "  width="100%">
  <tr align="left" class="forecasttext">
   <td><div id="bomalertvic"><?php include("rss-directbomvic.php");?></div><br/></td>
</div>
  </tr>
</table>
</span>
<!-- End BOM Alert VIC -->

<!-- Fire -->
<span id="e1" style="display:value">
<table style="background-color:#FFE991; border: thin solid; border-color: #4A4A4A;  "  width="100%">
  <tr align="left" class="forecasttext">
   <td><div id="firealertvic"><?php include("fireincidents.php");?></div><br/></td>
</div>
  </tr>
</table>
</span>
<!-- Fire -->





    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of jquery and what version of jquery ui? check browser support, you might be using a version that doesnt support IE

Comment: A lot of browser compat issues are due to broken HTML. You should run your code through the W3C validator, because there are a number of issues. Here's a direct link for you: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.micklehamweather.com%2Ftest.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in your code:

**Wrong:**

```
<td style="text-align:center" class="table-top" colspan="4"<span style="font-size: 100%; text-align:center;">
```

**Correct:**

```
<td style="text-align:center" class="table-top" colspan="4"><span style="font-size: 100%; text-align:center;">...</span>
```

### Hand Cursor on Mouse Hover:

If you want the hand/pointer cursor to show add this style:

```
<td style="text-align:center; cursor: pointer;" class="table-top" colspan="4"><span style="font-size: 100%; text-align:center;">...</span>
```

### Browser Compatibility:

As for IE, it's really hard to get everything working correctly. IE 9 has good support, but the older versions require much more work for maximum compatibility. But jQuery and jQuery UI should have much of it covered. As helpfully mentioned by @atmd, you should check your jQuery and jQuery UI versions. But at the end of the day some features will be broken on IE that that's the best developers can do.

Hope that answers your questions. If you have any more concerns, let me know in the comments.